# Help with Circuitikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, tikz-circuit-lib

I've been trying to experiment a bit with `circuitikz` to make my file look cleaner and take up less space (instead of using images from circuits diagram editors). 
I'm simply lost in all the examples and possibilities I've found online and I figured it's better to ask here and get a straight answer.

These are the two circuits I've been trying to make without much success:
[image]

This is my code:

```
    \begin{circuitikz}[scale=1] \draw
(0,0) to[battery2, v=f, invert] (0,4)
    to[R=R, -*] (4,4)
    to[voltmeter, l=$V_{mis}$] (4,2)
(4,2) --* (4,0)
    to[ammeter, l = $I_{mis}$] (5,2)
(5,0) -- (0,0)
;
\end{circuitikz}
```

which turns out like this (yikes):

[image]

Any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT**: I did it! Here's the code:

```
\begin{circuitikz}[scale=1] \draw
(0,0) to[battery2, v=f, invert] (0,4)
    to[R=R, -*] (4,4)
    to[voltmeter, l=$V_{mis}$, -*] (4,0) -- (0,0)
(4,4) -* (6,4)
    to[ammeter, l=$I_{mis}$] (6,2) to[R=$R_x$, -*] (6,0) -- (4,0)
;
\end{circuitikz}
```

and here's the final result:

[image]

I still don't know how to rotate the components (especially the voltmeter and amperometer) without making a fuss, so if anyone could help me in this regard it would be great.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229152/how-do-i-rotate-the-ammeter-in-circuitikz-so-that-the-a-in-symbol-uses-horizon is related to rotating, the solution is a bit complex though.

Comment: Please consider accepting the answers to your pervious questions (if you find them useful).

Comment: @Raaja is right, it seems that you are missing the "accept tick" feature of the network. Please, it is important to properly mark accepted the answers, to signal that the problem is solved.

Comment: @Rmano, yes I didn't know exactly how it worked. Thanks for your answer and for helping me understand how the network works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use the new version (0.9.2, but it's here since 0.9.0) you can use the new generic instruments:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
%\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikzgit}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[
    ]
        \draw
(0,0) to[battery2, v=f, ] (0,4)
    to[R=R, -*] (4,4)
    to[rmeterwa, t=V, l=$V_{mis}$, -*] (4,0) -- (0,0)
(4,4) -* (6,4)
    to[rmeterwa, t=A, l=$I_{mis}$] (6,2) to[R=$R_x$, -*] (6,0) -- (4,0)
;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can find a snapshot of the last version, with the documentation, in its [github page](https://circuitikz.github.io/circuitikz/). You just download the `circuitikzgit.sty` file, and use the second (commented out here) `\usepackage` instruction. Be sure to read the part about voltage and current orientation.

(By the way, given that these are circuits that I think will be used in class, consider the "QUCS-style" instruments; they show explicitly the type of internal connection --- short circuit for the ammeter, open circuit for the voltmeter).